# Multiple parameters in where clause

Tags: php, sql, propel

I need to append multiple parameters for where clause. Is there any way to achieve that using Propel. It gives me,

> Criteria:(Error: Could not build SQL for expression "LATITUDE" because Criteria::RAW works only with a clause containing a single question mark placeholder)

This is my query.

```
$userArray = UserQuery::create()
  ->where('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) )
    * cos( radians( User.latitude ) )
    * cos( radians( User.longitude ) - radians(?) )
    + sin( radians(?) )
    * sin( radians( User.latitude) ) ) ) > 10', 
    $user->getLatitude(),
    $user->getLongitude(),
    $user->getLatitude()
  )->find();
```

Comment: Did you try passing array as a first parameter to the where method?

Comment: Yes it is working. Try adding this a a answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try passing array as a first parameter to the where method? :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone referring this. I was able to achieve this using following code.

```
$userArray = UserQuery::create()->where('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) )
                                          * cos( radians( User.latitude ) )
                                          * cos( radians( User.longitude ) - radians(?) )
                                          + sin( radians(?) )
                                          * sin( radians( User.latitude) ) ) ) < 10000', 
                                          array($user->getLatitude(),
                                          $user->getLongitude(),
                                          $user->getLatitude()))->find();
```